# has_many :autosave => true skips validation when saving children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In both Rails 2 and Rails 3, if :autosave => true a has_many association, the collection is looped through and save(:validate => false) is called on each child association.  Why is that?  We need a before_validation callback to run for that child object, but it won't since it's a save that skips validation.

What's a good way around this?  And what is the purpose of skipping validations?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Validations **do** get run. There's a validation phase and a saving phase.  AutoSave attempts to do these two phases for the two models at the same time.  So, upon saving the parent model, the parent model is validated and then it's autosave child is validated.  After validations pass, the saving phase happens which saves the parent model and saves the child model (but skips validation).  The reason is because the validation has already been run.

I was running into a problem when I was trying to build the child model inside the parent during the before_save callback.  Therefore the associated object wasn't there to be validated during the validation phase.