# Rails throwing error on save (arguments 1 for 0) when saving through has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, rails-activerecord

Due to the nature of my use of 'updated_at' (specifically for use in atom feeds), I need to avoid updating the updated_at field when a record is saved without any changes. To accomplish that I read up and ended up with the following:

```
module ActiveRecord
    class Base

    before_validation :clear_empty_strings

    # Do not actually save the model if no changes have occurred.
    # Specifically this prevents updated_at from being changed
    # when the user saves the item without actually doing anything.
    # This especially helps when synchronizing models between apps.
    def save

        if changed?
            super
        else
            class << self
                def record_timestamps; false; end
            end
            super
            class << self
                remove_method :record_timestamps
            end
        end

    end

    # Strips and nils strings when necessary
    def clear_empty_strings
        attributes.each do |column, value|
            if self[column].is_a?(String)
                self[column].strip.present? || self[column] = nil
            end
        end
    end

    end
end
```

This works fine on all my models except for my Email model. An Email can have many Outboxes. An outbox is basically a two-column model that holds a subscriber (email To:) and an email (email to send to subscriber).  When I update the attributes of an outbox and then save Email, I get the (arguments 1 for 0) error on save (it points to the 'super' call in the save method).

Email.rb

```
has_many :outboxes, :order => "subscriber_id", :autosave => true
```

Outbox.rb

```
belongs_to :email, :inverse_of => :outboxes
belongs_to :subscriber, :inverse_of => :outboxes
validates_presence_of :subscriber_id, :email_id
attr_accessible :subscriber_id, :email_id
```

UPDATE: I also noticed that the 'changed' array isn't being populated when I change the associated models.

```
@email.outboxes.each do |out|
    logger.info "Was: #{ out.paused }, now: #{ !free }"
    out.paused = !free
end unless @email.outboxes.empty?
@email.save # Upon saving, the changed? method returns false...it should be true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...sigh. After spending countless hours trying to find a solution I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320723/has-many-autosave-true-skips-validation-when-saving-children). Has I known that the 'save' method actually takes an argument I would have figured this out sooner. Apparently looking at the [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save) didn't help in that regard. All I had to do was add an args={} parameter in the save method and pass it to 'super' and everything is working now. Unmodified records are saved without updating the timestamp, modified records are saved with the timestamp and associations are saved without error.

```
module ActiveRecord
    class Base

    before_validation :clear_empty_strings

    # Do not actually save the model if no changes have occurred.
    # Specifically this prevents updated_at from being changed
    # when the user saves the item without actually doing anything.
    # This especially helps when synchronizing models between apps.
    def save(args={})

    if changed?
        super args
    else
        class << self
        def record_timestamps; false; end
        end
        super args
        class << self
        remove_method :record_timestamps
        end
    end

    end

    # Strips and nils strings when necessary
    def clear_empty_strings
    attributes.each do |column, value|
        if self[column].is_a?(String)
        self[column].strip.present? || self[column] = nil
        end
    end
    end
end
```